# Erros in dynamically allocated array in C

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to dynamically allocate a 2D array, put some values, and print output. However it seems that I am making mistake in getting input to program in atoi() function.

Basically when we assign a static 2D array, we declare it as say int a [3][3]. So 3*3 units if int, that much memory gets allocated. Is same thing holds for allocating dynamic array as well?

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int arg,char* argv)
{
    int rows = atoi(argv[1]);
    int col = atoi(argv[2]);

    int rows =3;
    int col=3;
    int i,j;

    int (*arr)[col] = malloc(sizeof (*arr)*rows);

    int *ptr = &(arr[0][0]);
    int ct=1;
    for (i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<col;j++)
        {
            arr[i][j]=ct;
            ct++;
        }
    }   

    printf("printing array \n");
    for (i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<col;j++)
        {
            printf("%d \t",arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }   

    free(arr);

    return (0);
}
```

Program crashes in runtime. Can someone comment?

Comment: That won't compile, you are re-declaring `rows` and `cols`.

Comment: `main` is declared wrong. This means you have undefined behaviour right from the first `atoi`. This code should give you a lot of compiler warnings. pay attention to them and fix them before continuing.

Comment: To find *where* it crashes, you should use a debugger. If you build with debug information and run your program in a debugger, the debugger will stop at the location of the crash. If it's not in your code, then check the function call stack and walk up it until you are at your code. There you can then examine values of variables, which might help you understand what's wrong. If you still can't figure out what's wrong, at least you should update the question to point out the location of the crash.

Comment: Matt found and reported the important error. No wonder he gets no upvotes.

Answer (score 3):

Try to change the third line to:

```
int main(int arg,char **argv)
```

Answer (score 1):

The common method to use dynamic matrices is to use a pointer to pointer to something, and then allocate both "dimensions" dynamically:

```
int **arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * rows);
for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(**arr) * col);
```

Remember that to free the matrix, you have to free all "rows" in a loop first.

Comment: That has pros and cons; I think it is a bit overused compared to what is usually a simpler option of allocating a single block of memory . I'm extremely iffy about malloc'ing VLAs though so if he wants to have `col` found at runtime then your suggestion may be a lot safer!

Comment: Just allocating one chunk and using a bit more pointer arithmetic is just as common...

Answer (score 0):

```
int rows = atoi(argv[1]);
int col = atoi(argv[2]);

int rows =3;
int col=3;
int i,j;
```

You are defining rows and col twice.... that would never work!

Answer (score 0):

With traditional C, you can only have the `array[][]` structure for multiple dimension arrays work with compile time constant values. Otherwise, the pointer arithmetic is not correct.

For dynamically sized multi dimensional arrays (those where rows and cols are determined at runtime), you need to do additional pointer arithmetic of this type:

```
int *a;
int rows=3;
int cols=4;
a = malloc(rows * cols * sizeof(int));
for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
   for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
   a[i*rows + j] = 1;

free(a);
```

Alternatively, [you can use double indirection and have an array of pointers each pointing to a one dimensional array](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/dynmuldimary.html).

If you are using GCC or any C99 compiler, dynamic calculation of multiple dimension arrays is simplified by using [variable length arrays](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html):

```
// This is your code -- simplified
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int rows = atoi(argv[1]);
    int col = atoi(argv[2]);

    // you can have a rough test of sanity by comparing rows * col * sizeof(int) < SIZE_MAX

    int arr[rows][col];     // note the dynamic sizing of arr here

    int ct=1;
    for (int i=0;i<rows;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<col;j++)
            arr[i][j]=ct++;

    printf("printing array \n");
    for (int i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<col;j++)
        {
            printf("%d \t",arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}  // arr automatically freed off the stack
```

With a variable length array ("VLA"), dynamic multiple dimension arrays in C become far easier.

Compare:

```
void f1(int m, int n)
{
    // dynamically declare an array of floats n by m size and fill with 1.0
    float *a;
    a = malloc(m * n * sizeof(float));
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
      for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        a[i*n + j] = 1.0;
    free(a);    
}
```

With VLA you can write to do the same:

```
void f2(int m, int n)
{
  // Use VLA to dynamically declare an array of floats n by m size and fill with 1.0  
  float a[m][n];
  for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
      a[i][j] = 1.0;
}
```

Be aware that unlike `malloc / free` VLA's handling of requesting a size larger than what is available on the stack is not as easily detected as using `malloc` and testing for a NULL pointer. VLA's are essentially [automatic variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable) and have similar ease and restrictions.

VLA's are better used for smaller data structures that would be on the stack anyway. Use the more robust `malloc / free` with appropriate detection of failure for larger data structures.

If you are not using a fairly recent vintage C compiler that supports C99 -- time to get one.